# Write your own 9P server for Windows?

Tags: winapi, network-programming, windows-10, filesystems, plan-9

Since version 1903, Windows 10 can mount [9P](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) network file systems. This is used from WSL. You can run, in Linux, "explorer.exe " and then see in Windows, a "network" (but local) share from your Linux instance.

Is this protocol open to use by other programs than WSL? I.e. could this new 9P client in Windows be used as an alternative to [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/) or [WinFsp](http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/)?

(Or is this 9P API internal to WSL and can only be originated from within WSL?)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4070 alas not yet. On the other hand, one can make ones' own WSL2 kernel! https://microhobby.com.br/blog/2019/09/21/compiling-your-own-linux-kernel-for-windows-wsl2/

Answer (score 0):

9P is an open protocol. As of right now there is no possibility to configure client in Windows to enable third-party connections without some hacking.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9P_(protocol)

Comment: **a)** Yes, 9P is an open protocol, but it wouldn't be the first time Microsoft extended a protocol. Not saying they did here, I don't see any indication of that, but I wouldn't exactly be *shocked*. **b)** What kind of hacking? (Otherwise this answer kind of just rephrases my question with fewer words.) BTW I really appreciated https://zeptobars.com/en/read/sem-selfie-bsd-backscattered-electron-secondary-EDS - I could never have guessed that such a thing was possible. Like an inverted pin-hole camera or something. I don't understand how it's possible to be frank :-D

Comment: @Prof.Falken b) Hacking - creating dummy VM, intercepting OS<>VM communication and forwarding data elsewhere... Have not seen anyone attempting to do it yet - but I am sure someone eventually will, 9P in windows is quite young.